# Medium.com stories don't work as Articles in Careers 2.0

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, jobs

I wrote an article for Medium.com that hit #18 on the top 100 and has over 100,000 views. This is a big accomplishment for me and I'd like to include it my Careers 2.0 profile, but I get a 'could not retrieve that URL' error which I try to add it.

Is there a workaround for this, or is this something that can be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Confirmed... we're looking into this.

Comment: Seems to be a problem fetching some sites via https - unfortunately that's the only way of connecting to medium.com as plain http redirects to https. I'm looking into it. It's affecting some other https sites too.

Comment: This is an ongoing issue but appears to be intermittent - it's working right now for example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now fixed this. There was a part of our configuration which could cause an outgoing HTTPS connection to fail. This should now work properly, so we're always able to fetch the title and description of articles from medium.com (as well as some other HTTPS sites which were intermittently failing before).